# unable to see request logs in webpack-dev-server

Tags: logging, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am using `webpack-dev-server` to act as a CDN server locally to serve various static assets like css, js, html etc.

Everything runs fine but for debugging purposes, I am unable to see the requests received by the CDN server.

`webpack-dev-server` just goes silent and doesn't show any info/errors once it has compiled the bundle of static assets.

I went through the command line help too but with no success.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Basically, `webpack-dev-server` uses `express` to spawn a webserver. To enable seeing logs, one needs to set DEBUG environment variable as required by express

```
export DEBUG='express:*'
```

This started showing me logs of various requests received by `webpack-dev-server`.

To disable the logs, set the environment variable empty again

```
export DEBUG=
```

This works even for `loopback` projects and any other NodeJS frameworks which use express as base.

Comment: @Juicy which webpack version are you using?

Comment: @MEnf just make DEBUG environment variable empty `export DEBUG=`

Comment: Which file does this need to be added to?

Comment: its a command to be run on terminal or the script which populates your environment variables

Answer (score 5):

the environment variable didn't worked for me.

According to the docs, you can add your own custom middleware via **before** (add this to vue.config.js):

```
devServer: {
    disableHostCheck: true,
    host: 'localhost',
    https: {
        key: fs.readFileSync('./dev/ssl-localhost-testing/server.key'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('./dev/ssl-localhost-testing/server.cert'),
    },
    before: function (app, server, compiler) {
        app.use('/', function (req, res,next) {
            console.log(`from ${req.ip} - ${req.method} - ${req.originalUrl}`);
            next();
        });
    }
 }
```

This logs each request to the console like:

```
from 127.0.0.1 - GET - /js/BACC_AtlasAdministration.js
```

Maybe this helps somebody

Comment: with `webpack-dev-server` version 4 `before(app, server, compiler)` became `onBeforeSetupMiddleware(devServer)` and `app.use` must be changed to `devServer.app.use`

Comment: Which is now deprectaed in favour of `setupMiddlewares`: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserversetupmiddlewares