# See webpack dev server logging

Tags: vue.js, webpack-dev-server

I have a vue-CLI project. Is there a simple way of viewing requests to the webpack dev server?

i.e. in the console after i've ran `npm run dev` and I get the message `Your application is running here: http://localhost:8081` etc, I would like to see the hits to the webserver

I've added DEBUG='express:*'to my environment variables (windows) but it seems to make no difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable to see request logs in webpack-dev-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41822032/unable-to-see-request-logs-in-webpack-dev-server)

Comment: Yeah I saw that post, I did try to add DEBUG = EXPRESS:* to my environment variables but it made no difference

Comment: Weird, on a fresh `vue init webpack` template, `env DEBUG="express:*" npm run dev` worked for me (your shell might not require `env` there)

Comment: I'm running windows(10) which probably breaks things, but the environment variable is definitely set, but no logging

Answer (score 2):

Windows is funny. The standard approach is to use `set VAR=val && webpack-dev-server...` but that doesn't work on UNIX. I couldn't come up with a single command that would work on both a Windows and a UNIX shell.

Instead, to keep everything consistent, I'm now using the handy helper module [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env)

It's designed for exactly this purpose, and is easy to use. Just use `cross-env` where you'd typically use UNIX-style env, and away you go. Mine, for example, looks like:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env DEBUG=express:router webpack-dev-server ...."
}
```

This gives me portable request logging from webpack in development mode.